# Are the Aramaic root ק.ב.ל and the Hebrew root ק.ב.ל related?

Tags: etymology, words, hebrew, aramaic

When the word מקבילות comes up in *parashas T'ruma*, Rash"i defines it based on the Aramaic root ק.ב.ל, commonly found in the preposition לקבל (against or opposite) to mean physically across from/corresponding to. Is this root etymologically related or identical to the Hebrew root of the same spelling meaning accept or receive?

(If not, which is the operative root in the phrase *kabalas panim*?)

Comment: Note also the other Hebrew root, meaning to complain.

Comment: msh210, I do believe that the meaning "to complain" is a variation of either the Aramaic meaning "facing opposite" or the Hebrew meaning "to receive" as in a plaintiff, who when he is in the right will receive his due. The meaning "to receive" is in the binyan pi'eil and "to complain" is in the binyan pa'ahl.

Comment: Note that there is another Aramaic root קבל, meaning "dark" or "humble," as in לעולם הוי קבל וקיים (Sanhedrin 92a).

Comment: @msh210 @Yahu @Alex Duly noted.

Comment: I'd always assumed "kabalas panim" meant receiving people's presences.

Comment: You find the Aramaic "kol k'veil" meaning "as a result of", most likely related to the idea of "correspondence." As to whether "correspondence" and "receiving" are related ... well, probably distantly. Just as "weigh" and "take" (shin-kuf-lamed) are, or "ascend" and "arrive" (ayin-lamed-heh) are, in Hebrew and Aramaic, respectively.

Comment: How would the Hebrew word, makbil מקביל, meaning "parallel," fit in with this? Is one line, opposite the other? Something to ponder.

Comment: @Madeleine, that's the word the OP was asking about in the first place.

Comment: It's interesting the word has so many meanings, see also [Targum Shemos 22:22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/cu0206.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hebrew and Aramaic קבל qbl have the same origins, though qbl came into popular use in Hebrew (instead of לקח) only later, towards the Mishnaic period, under Aramaic influence.

Yes, there is a base meaning "facing", though the most common word from this root in Hebrew,  qibbel  means "receive" (with the obvious relation to the base meaning).

Comment: If I understand correctly, the original meaning of the root is "facing" and the others are derivatives?

Comment: It seems that that's the case.

Comment: If I understand _Ramba"m_ on [_Avos_ 3:12](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%92_%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93#.D7.9E.D7.A9.D7.A0.D7.94_.D7.99.D7.91) correctly, the _hif'il_ version is Aramaic and means "facing" or "corresponding" but the are the same root.